# Processing data with multiple labels for same features Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm completely new to Pandas, so hopefully this question isn't too newb.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
 feature1 feature2 feature3 label
 a        2        3         1
 b        2        3         1
 c        2        3         0
```

In this case, I want to get a single matching of feature2 and feature3 to a label. Feature1 in this case is just a unique ID for each row and does not help in this case (and most likely, I will end up dropping this feature)

So what I want to end up with is the following because I will use the mode label.

```
 feature1 feature2 feature3 label
 a        2        3         1
```

From another stackoverflow post, I'm using this code:

```
  processed_data = raw_data.groupby(['feature2','feature3']).agg(lambda 
  x:x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```

Is this the correct way to do this? I've spot checked a few data points and it seems to be correct, but based on the value_counts() doc I'm not fully convinced this is doing what I want it to do. Moreso when I look at my processed_data, I will see a feature1 = x which corresponds to a single row, so it seems more like this code just picked a single row instead of picking the mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, it is correct. You can also specify column `label`:

```
processed_data = (df.groupby(['feature2','feature3'])['label']
                   .agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
                   .reset_index())
```

Another solution:

```
processed_data = (df.groupby(['feature2','feature3'])['label']
                    .agg(lambda x:x.mode())
                    .reset_index())

print (processed_data)
   feature2  feature3  label
0         2         3      1
```

But if want aggregate mode from `label` column and `first` value of `feature1` columns use:

```
processed_data = (df.groupby(['feature2','feature3'])
                   .agg({'label':lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0], 'feature1':'first'})
                   .reset_index()
                   .reindex(columns=df.columns))
print (processed_data)
  feature1  feature2  feature3  label
0        a         2         3      1
```

Comment: Thanks! So I'm curious, how will value_counts or mode() handle ties? Based on the data, it seems like if there is a tie it sets the label to be 1 and I'm assuming this is just based on how it orders the data? Also, because each row has a unique feature1, how does it know how to count up the values or take the mode based on the label and not feature1?

Comment: @Kevin - Hmmm, not sure if understand. But try explain code. First groupby for all groups created by columns `feature2` and `feature3` use functions from `agg`, so here for `0,1,1` return `mode`. If change `df.groupby(['feature2','feature3'])['label'].mean()` it return `mean`. Order of values is not important in `label` column, only if use function `first` or `last`. But not 100% sure if understand what you need.

Comment: So what I mean here is what if you have 4 datapoints with labels 0, 0, 1, 1. How does it pick the mode here? I assume it's based on the sort algorithm. Is there a way to make the algorithm pick merge sort which would be stable?

Comment: @Kevin - I am not pandas developer, I really have no idea. Try ask in [pands github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)